# PDE with a Dirac Delta function as boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I would like to have some information how to solve this PDE:
$\partial_tu(x,t)=k^2\partial_{xx}u(x,t)$
with the following boundary and initial conditions:
$u(x,0)=u_0(x)$,$u(0,t)=\delta(t-t_0)$,$u(L,t)=u_L(t)$
Thanks.

Comment: You mean "you would like to know how to solve this PDE ... under the boundary and initial conditions..."? I juust want to understand your question please.

Comment: And adding your own thoughts is welcome, too

Comment: What did block you? Have you already used, for example, separation of variables?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi: just corrected the question. Just a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical Diffusion PDE, if I have understood your question correctly.

In fact its solution was marking the birthday of Fourier technique. The straight forward solution is really standard literature since 190 years and you will find [it >>> here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Solving_the_heat_equation_using_Fourier_series) for the so called *Heat Equation* as invented by Fourier. It would be quite redundant to copy/paste all hereto.

When applying the technique you particularly arrive to the point where the constants *A, B, C* need to be at final steps identified, there you should apply instead, your own boundary/initial conditions.

This should equip you best for the solution of the problem.